# In Android, how to temporarily suspend the changes to a view for a period of time?

Tags: android, view, textview, locking, suspend

Based on my design (too complicated to introduce all the details, I will ask using a simplified example in words), I need to suspend the changes (may be called from different places) to a view (say TextView) for a period of time (given parameter). The description of the problem is as follows:

There is a TextView, named messageDisplay, which displays text updates of many types of on-going statuses (the updates can be given from multiple places). messageDisplay will be updated whenever the setText function is called (the new message replaces the old one). Now, I want to make it pause (or hold/lock the display) for some time if the current message belongs to certain types (say contains certain keywords), and it is ok for other messages not getting the chance of being displayed in the mean time. In other words, once the condition is met, messageDisplay is suspended for changes, until certain time elapses. There are other views/activities, so I do not want to pause the whole app, just the messageDisplay.

Is there a simple solution or a set of function calls to achieve the objective? Or must I define a time interval and write my own function to check whenever a setText call is made, whether it will be denied to execute based on the suspension interval?

Thank you for any discussions or comments!

Comment: Hide the TextView (set it invisible) and set its value to another one (which is under it). In reverse oder: 1) Set the text, 2) hide it.

Comment: This is not a discussion site. Please post some work you have done. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: just create a custom TextView and override `setText` put your condition in some controller interface and pass an instance of controller to it.

Comment: Use Snackbar to display temporal info